# How to copy and paste multiple sheet for column's data with the same column name to another excel file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have two different Excel files One is the master I need to update and the second one contains the data I need to copy and paste So....

This is my master excel file I want to update looks like this

[Excel Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq781.png)

and this excel which contains column data I need to copy it to the `master file`, as thee's are three sheets called `GSM_CDDData`, `UMTS_CDDData`, and `LTE_CDDData` and the three sheets contains the same column name which I need to copy it's data and add them to the `Master Excel`, as the columns name is `CELLNAME`

and this excel looks like

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMY8X.png)

After Copying this data ,I want to paste them in the `Master Excel` in column called `CELL`

So any Ideas how to do that?.....

as I know the supported library `pandas` and `openpyxl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy and paste the data itself, you might consider use of the pywin32 package (if you have Windows)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file_name)
ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(sheet_1)
ws2 = wb1.Worksheets(sheet_2)
ws1.Columns(index_number).Copy(ws2.Columns(index_number))
```

If you don't want to use pywin32, you might just import the various columns using

```
pd.read_excel()
```

and append or concatenate the objects. From there you can save the new dataframe using to_excel.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support,
but could you specify your answer with details according to my `Data Example` excel :)

Comment: as I have Windows for my case :)